# How do i delete a flash drive with a raspberry pi 4?

Tags: usb, usb3

So i accidentally got loads of stuff on my flash drive, and i want to delete all that stuff, and i can delete it file by file but that would take forever, i tried deleting folder by folder instead but it wouldn't work through a flash drive, anyway to wipe out everything on a flash drive?

Answer (score 1):

This is great opportunity for you to learn some terminal commands. You have to find the mount point path of your drive. Might be something like /mnt/usb0 (do some sleuthing to figure out exactly what it is)

then in your terminal change directory to your mount point `cd /mnt/usb0` and then recursively delete all folders and files `rm -rf *`

Formatting the drive would work too, but the question you're asking here definitely implies that you don't have much terminal experience and it's worth learning the basics if you want to use linux for anything serious

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to format it. You could also use the rm -r or rmdir command, I am not sure about the syntax. man rm or rmdir will give you help.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided no information "i accidentally got loads of stuff on my flash drive". How is it formatted? What "stuff"? What OS? What is on the drive?

It is simple to delete, but I am reluctant to post as the same command can easily delete your OS if incorrectly executed.